# Simple Yes or No Source Transformation questions

Tags: circuit-analysis

I know I can compute source transformations using the method shown here in the blue index card here https://i.stack.imgur.com/347ky.jpg.

I used both of these methods, in an exercise here https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ab1K.jpg

My solution is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQhEv.jpg

Now, I have some questions about this sample circuit here https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xLuE.jpg

1. I know if I remove Va, R1, and R3 from the circuit, I can source transform Is and R4.
2. If I remove R3 from the circuit, can I source transform Is and R4? I understand that the possible answers are "No, Va and R1 affect the circuit... don't allow this...", and "Yes, Va and R1 are both strictly parallel to Is and R4 so you can source transform."

Sorry for the links. I tried to directly upload the images in-line but they were too large.

Comment: Irfan view can decimate file sizes easily...No, Yes

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 . So to question (2), the answer is yes? and thus the voltage source and resistor in parallel,  Va and R1 to the left of Is and R4, do not stop me from using a modification and source transformation on Is and R4 into a voltage source Is*R4 and a series resistor R4? Thanks

Comment: YES a Voltage source = 0 Ohms . Got it?

Comment: Great! I will experiment to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: Trust but verify, then ok